# Регулярные выражения в Sublime text 3

Tags: регулярные-выражения, sublime-text

Есть регулярное выражение:
    "\d{1},\d{1}"
Необходимо заменить у найденных значений "," на "." и убрать кавычки (из "4,5" должно получиться 4.5).
Какое регулярное выражение необходимо вставить в строку Replase?

Буду благодарен помощи.

[image: Внешний вид интерфейса Sublime text 3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для VSC:

```
// regexp
"(\d{1}),(\d{1})"

// replacement 
// $1.$2
```

По идее и для Sublime должно подойти.